# What can I do to make edge-scrolling work in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, hardware, scrolling

I just recently installed Kubuntu 18.04 on my Dell Latitude E6520 and everything seems to be working just fine except for one thing. I am unable to use edge-scrolling on the touchpad and when I attempt to edit the settings they will never save after clicking "Apply".

The only thing that I have that might be non-standard is having my /home/ directory on another partition.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I was able to answer the question myself. I figured I'd post my solution here for anyone who is having this issue in the future. It was as simple as running the following command and rebooting:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

After the reboot (at least in my case) side-scrolling on my touchpad works with no additional configuration or installs needed. Anyone who thinks this was a bad solution, please let me and other interested parties know!

Hope this helps someone.